# Import a JADE file to NetBeans IDE?

Tags: java, netbeans-8, agents-jade

How to import a `JADE` example project (already done the project) into `NetBeans IDE`? I have tried to import it. But it was not working. How to do it correctly? I am a beginner to JADE.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that your question states precisely which the problem is.

Nevertheless, assuming that all `JADE` functionality is broken when you import your project, i feel that your problem is that you haven't download the `jade.jar` file and you haven't imported it to your `Netbeans` project.

The procedure of importing a jar into `Netbeans` is trivial and has been answered in Stack Overflow.

Hope it helps.

PS: Please give us more input about your problem is my answer is short.